# How to exploit QR factorization implicitly

Tags: numerics, linear-solver, matrix-factorization

I meet a problem when I try to develop an iterative method for discrete inverse problem
$$Ax+e=b$$
where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $e$ is a noise. I want to approximate the true solution $x_{true}$ by using a nonlinear regularization term $R(x)$. Since $m,n$ is very large, the optimal regularization parameter is very hard to choose, and an iterative regularization method is needed.

My idea is using a iterative reweighted process to approximate $R(x)$ at each step $k$. Suppose at step $k-1$, we have computed $x_{k-1}$, then at step $k$, we construct a regularization matrix $L_k$ to approximate $R(x)$, i.e. let $\|L_kx_{k-1}\|_2=R(x_{k-1})$ (obviously $L_k$ depends on $x_{k-1}$ as well as the particular expression of $R(x)$).

Now the problem is to solve $Ax+e=b$ with changed regularization matrix $L_k$ (may be not square). Following the paper "Kilmer M E, Hansen P C and Español M I 2007: A projection-based approach to general-form Tikhonov regularization, SIAM J. Sci. Comput. 29, 315–30", I want to modify the original joint bidiagonalization algorithm by using changed matrix pairs $\{A,L_k\}$ at each step, which can exploit the properties of $L_k$ into $A$ by using changed preconditioner $R_{k}^{-1}$ of QR factorization
$$\begin{pmatrix}
    A \\L_k
\end{pmatrix}=Q_kR_k.$$

This leads to the problem that $R_{k}^{-1}v$ and $AR_{k}^{-1}v$ need to be computed at each iteration. However, the explicit computation of QR and $R_{k}^{-1}$ is unaffordable since $A$ and $L_k$ is very large.

A simple consideration is to solve the problem
$$\begin{pmatrix}
    A \\L_k
\end{pmatrix}z_k = Q_kv$$
by an iterative linear solver to approximate $z_k=R_{k}^{-1}v$, but $Q_k$ is still unknown without an explicit QR factorization.

So is there any iterative method to approximate $R_{k}^{-1}v$ implicitly?